# Meteor.userId().username is "undefined" when user is logged in

Tags: javascript, meteor

So, I have a logged in user (myself) in my app. I know I'm logged in, because my username is displayed in the page. However, in my Javascript, I am unable to get my username assigned to a variable.

My main.js file contains this:

```
var uniqueID = Meteor.userId();
var username = uniqueID.username;
console.log("uniqueID = "+uniqueID);
console.log("username = "+username);
```

The console log shows:

```
uniqueID = XGX8Qas2ZLCwNYxTH
username = undefined
```

I tried the following line in the js file based on a post with a similar issue:

```
var username2 = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: Meteor.userId() }).username
```

This caused an outright error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined)

Now, in the browser console, if I put in:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({ _id : "XGX8Qas2ZLCwNYxTH" })
```

I get the expected response: {_id: "XGX8Qas2ZLCwNYxTH", username: "welehman"}

So I am at a complete loss as to how to pull in the username. I actually had this working before, but now that I actually need it, of course it suddenly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want here is the whole user record, not just the id:

```
var uniqueID = Meteor.user(); // Not Meteor.userId()
var username = uniqueID.username; // This will work then
```

Also then promptly change the uniqueID variable to a more suitable name, as it holds the whole user not just the ID now.

Comment: With that code (copied exactly), I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined" on the line where the variable "username" is define. Doing some quick variations, I notice that Meteor.user() is actually "undefined" and therefore the (new) variable "username" is also undefined. Oddly, Meteor.userId() still produces that huge string.

Comment: I guess you are trying to get the user on the client side, right? In that case it depends when the user data is published. This is a reactive construct, which means the user will propagate from the server to the client eventually. What you can do is to assign the Meteor.user() to a variable in a Tracker.autorun block and then the variable will contain the whole user object and from that point you do what you need with that data. `Tracker.autorun(() => { let user = Meteor.user() ... }`

Comment: I think that's it. I moved the variable definition to a chronologically later function and it worked! I guess the data didn't have time to load.